# Twitter Oauth 2.0 making requests on behalf of other users

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use the [PKCE](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token) flow for the user authentication.

After successful redirection by using the following pattern:

https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=M1M5R3BMVy13QmpScXkzTUt5OE46MTpjaQ&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com&scope=tweet.read%20users.read%20follows.read%20offline.access&state=state&code_challenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain

I got the code, but then when I try to get the access token the following request fails:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base 64 encode>' \
--data-urlencode 'code=<code received>' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=<my_redirect>' \
--data-urlencode 'code_verifier=challenge' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<my_client_id>'
```

Error message is `{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Missing valid authorization header"}`

I tried to use all of the methods described here for the Basic header, but none of them were successful:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-generate-a-bear-token-for-api-2-authentication/171837

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 11):

In you App > User authentication settings > Click on edit for OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0 > Turn on both OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0 and Change Type of App to "Single Page App" which should be Public client.

Comment: Is this still up to date? I can't find any of these things on User authentication settings page.

Comment: If you are using the new OAuth 2.0 flow, looks like if you choose "confidential client" in the "user authentication setup" of the client it breaks sometimes even if you provide a correct Authentication Basic header.

My workaround was to change it to "public client" and include the client_id in the body, it should be safe since you are mostly using Auth Code Flow w/ PKCE.

Comment: Hello @Haris jamal, i have turned this on public client but I have this error : Error fetching OAuth credentials: "Value passed for the authorization code was invalid.".

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue and spent hours trying to diagnose it. I ended up deleting the app I created in the Twitter Developer Platform, and creating a new app, generating the `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` in the exact same way and it now works.

Possibly a bug on Twitters side?

Comment: Same happend with me. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

To create the basic authorization header you will need to base64 encoding on your Client ID and Client Secret which can be obtained from your App’s “Keys and Tokens” page inside of the developer portal.
You can generate the Authorization here: [Base64 Encode](https://www.base64encode.org/).
use: {ClientID}:{ClientSecret} not apiid and apisecret.

If you choose to use **confidential client**, you don't need a *client_id* in your request body, if you do so, that would trigger a bug in twitter which returns an error code.